# PowerShell Posh-Git autocomplete stop when multiple options exist

Tags: git, powershell, autocomplete, posh-git

Is there a way to configure Posh-Git PowerShell module autocomplete feature in a non-greedy way?

Current behavior for input "git checkout fea" will autocomplete to "git checkout feature/my-feature-1". I would like for it to autocomplete to "git checkout feature/my-feature-" if there are "feature/my-feature-1" and "feature/my-feature-2" branches.

More generic form of the question: is there a way for autocomplete to complete only the part that is not ambiguous?

Thanks!